# What does impedance control on a PCB mean

Tags: pcb, resistance, impedance

I understand that when the electrical length is less than 1/10 of the trace length I would have to go in for impedance matching. A PCB impedance is controlled by its stack up. THat is thickness of prepreg, copper etc. So when a factory says it does impedance control , does it mean that they do that kind of a stack up? What does it mean when a factory says they will not do impedance control? Is it that they cannot do that stackup? If so , sticking to a normal 4 layer board stack is sufficient? What is th main FR4 specification that determines the impedance? Because right now I have a boards which has a stack up for 4 layers with thickness of each layer. DO I have to send this stack up to every PCB house and ask if they do this? How do I build these boards?

Comment: Trace impedance is typically only considered for high speed signals. Does your circuit contain high speed signals?

Comment: USB and DDR signals, so yes high speed

Comment: Do you understand the basic concepts of impedance matching and high-speed signal routing? It's not clear from you question if you have experience here. But routing DDR signals would imply you do have experience.

Comment: @DanLaks, I didnt route the board. I do know the the load should appear as 50ohm , , and this is controlled by the trace length and width on top of a ground plane, but thats all

Comment: Honestly, there are too many misconceptions and lack of understanding to answer this question reasonably.

Comment: Well what are the misconceptions?

Comment: What Matt means is this is a very large subject with lots of information to cover to properly answer this question, as well as correct a few misconceptions you have. I've thought about how I would answer it, but realized I don't have time today to write the answer I would need to write. I may write something later, time permitting.

Comment: Trace length does not affect  the impedance. Trace width is the important factor.

Comment: @derstrom8 - the question does not propose that trace length would control impedance, rather it proposes that trace length (relatively to an admittedly odd statement of wavelength) would determine if impedance matching is *important*.  And that is correct.

Comment: Thank you Chris, you're absolutely right. I misread the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I understand that when the electrical length is less than 1/10 of the trace length I would have to go in for impedance matching.

You have this backwards, the common rule is to use impedance control when the electrical length of the trace is *more* than 1/10 of a wavelength at the frequency of interest. (Like Rolf points out in his answer, the "frequency of interest" is more related to the rise and fall times of a digital signal than to the data rate)

> So when a factory says it does impedance control , does it mean that they do that kind of a stack up?

It means they can control the thickness of the dielectric layer and the width of the trace with close enough tolerance to guarantee impedance matching to within some specified limits (often +/- 10%)

Also, like the other answer points out, they should have test equipment to allow them to verify the boards they produce.

> What does it mean when a factory says they will not do impedance control?

It means they can't control the geometry closely enough to guarantee the impedance is within tolerance.

> Is it that they cannot do that stackup?

No the stackup doesn't change, it's how well controlled the geometry is.

> If so , sticking to a normal 4 layer board stack is sufficient?

No, you need to control the geometry well to be able to get the required impedance.

> What is th main FR4 specification that determines the impedance?

Dielectric constant, often designated \$\epsilon_r\$ or \$D_k\$ is the critical material parameter.

The thickness of the dielectric is also critical.

> Because right now I have a boards which has a stack up for 4 layers with thickness of each layer. DO I have to send this stack up to every PCB house and ask if they do this?

You just have to send it to one board shop that knows how to do impedance control, or 2 or 3 if you want to get competitive bids.

Many many board shops are capable of impedance control, including many of the modest-priced shops that advertise online. Only the most low-cost shops (and probably most of the hobbyist shops that charge by the square centimeter and combine your design with others) can't do it.

> How do I build these boards?

Send the manufacturing files to a board shop with capabilities that match your requirements, and pay them to build them for you.

Comment: Not 100% in agreement here, but liked the format. So I created a separate answer.

Comment: I would note that it is highly unlikely that any two PCB houses will specify the same stack and track rules for a given impedance.

Comment: This is a very good answer. I would like to add, however, that the manufacturer may suggest different stackups that are easier for them to manufacture, in which case you may need to change the geometry of your traces (the widths, primarily) to make sure the impedance is matched properly. I use the EEWeb calculator at work: https://www.eeweb.com/toolbox/microstrip-impedance . I generally aim for a trace width that gives me an impedance 10% higher than the target because surrounding traces will reduce the impedance of a particular trace.

Comment: @PeterSmith, I guess that's true. I tend to work where I determine the stack up (down to the laminate product number, consulting with the board shop to see what they stock), and use a calculator to find a "close-enough" trace width. Then the board shop runs Polar to get a final trace width, usually within a half a thou of what my calculation gave.

Comment: No, the poster doesn't have it backwards.  They are just using odd terminology - clearly the mentioned "electrical length" is the wavelength in a conductor.  And the important question is if the trace length is more than a meaningful fraction of that, as correctly stated.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, The term [electrical length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_length) has a well established meaning in engineering. If OP used it to mean something entirely different from what the broader engineering community uses it for, that's not my fault.

Comment: That is what the poster is referring to - the problem is that you then inverted their comparison in order to falsely criticize it.  Even at your own link, it is stated that electrical length is often given in wavelengths.  The poster is comparing a physical length of the actual trace, to the physical length of a trace that would have a one wavelength electrical length.  Your mistake is in thinking they are comparing a determined electrical length to a period, but they are not - instead, they are comparing a specific trace to a prefigured physical length that is electrically  a wavelength.

Comment: Of course details of the circuit - anything that changes the velocity factor, and any lumped elements, will throw that comparison off as the relationship between physical and electrical length then varies, but it is not a bad place to start, to have a mental sense of a trace length where one does need to start to worry.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Yes electrical length can be given in wavelengths. But it's still a measure of the length of the trace. OP's version of the rule is "when the electrical length is less than 1/10 of the trace length" which is basically the same as "the trace length is less than 1/10 of the trace length (although measured in different units)".

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I have reworded my first paragraph, do you like that better?

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that when the electrical length is less than 1/10 of the
>   trace length I would have to go in for impedance matching.

Actually what you should look at is the risetime compared to the lenght of the traces. So if you have 200-300ps risetime and you have a 100-150ps long trace or *shorter* this *may* go fine without termination.

> So when a factory says it does impedance control , does it mean that
>   they do that kind of a stack up?

It most likely means they have a TDR to verify impedance of test traces after they build the board. Often from [Polar Instruments](http://www.polarinstruments.com/products/cits/cits880s.html)

> What does it mean when a factory says they will not do impedance
>   control? It means they can't control the geometry closely enough to
>   guarantee the impedance is within tolerance.

That this is a cheap shop that is not fit for building high speed boards.

> If so , sticking to a normal 4 layer board stack is sufficient?

Depends on your definition of normal. Roughly speaking - and you will have to do the calculations - if you route on the two outer layers only you will need a prepreg thickness between the outer layers and your two inner layer power/gnd planes similar to the trace width. So for 6mil traces, about 6mil thick prepreg. Again: You will have to do the calculation - and it's easy to do with a free tool you can find on the net called TNT.

> What is th main FR4 specification that determines the impedance?

Since the dielectric constant, often designated ϵr or Dk is almost the same for all material (around 4), the most important thing is the thickness.

> Because right now I have a boards which has a stack up for 4 layers
>   with thickness of each layer. DO I have to send this stack up to every
>   PCB house and ask if they do this?

See the answer from "The Proton".

> How do I build these boards?

See the answer from "The Proton".

Let me know if this helped, or you have further questions?

Also, strongly consider an 8L board (routing-gnd-pwr-routing-(fat core)-routing-pwr-gnd-routing) as it's much easier to route AND get the power distribution (PDN) right. Without good PDN you quickly run into trouble getting the thing to run fast reliably.

Disclaimer: I teach courses in SI and often have Polar Instruments as a sponsor - but I do not receive any kickback.

Comment: Regarding TNT, are you referring to [this software](http://mmtl.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I think TNT is technically speaking the graphical front-end for MMTL :) @dionys